# Download an image from a url that has a splash page (ip camera)

Tags: vb.net

So I'm trying to download an image from a url path. I'm using the following code which is tested and does work:

```
Client.DownloadFile("URL","FILE LOCATION")
Client.Dispose()
```

The url I'm using is the ip address of a camera that provides static jpg images. But the issue is the first time you visit the url it asks you to pick a language on a splash page. If you either chose a language or simply try the url for a second time it will bring you to the correct url with the jpg and will completely bypass this "language splash screen" any time in the future. So the question is how do I get my code to refresh/relaunch the url before downloading the image?

UPDATE:
So the website does create a cookie. This is what I was able to pull from google chrome about it:

```
Name:   LANGUAGE
Content:    0
Domain: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
Path:   /cgi-bin
Send for:   Any kind of connection
Accessible to script:   Yes
Created:    Friday, May 24, 2013 8:27:05 AM
Expires:    When the browsing session ends
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the page creates a cookie with a default lang.
 Try using GET/POST with a cookie container.

```
Dim logincookie As CookieContainer 'You can use this CookieContainer to do another request.


        Dim postData As String = ""
        Dim url as String = "yourUrl"
        Dim tempCookies As New CookieContainer
        Dim encoding As New UTF8Encoding
        Dim byteData As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

        Dim postReq As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        postReq.Method = "POST" 'GET or POST
        postReq.KeepAlive = True
        postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies
        postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        postReq.Referer = url
        postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)"
        postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length

        Dim postreqstream As Stream = postReq.GetRequestStream()
        postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length)
        postreqstream.Close()
        Dim postresponse As HttpWebResponse

        postresponse = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies)
        logincookie = tempCookies
        Dim postreqreader As New StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream())

        Dim thepage As String = postreqreader.ReadToEnd

        msgbox(thepage)
```

Comment: Also I tried your code and I get `A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.`

Comment: @peter Hello Petter, try using **Keep Alive to false**. Also if you can run this firefox addon, check for any posts the page make. https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/

Comment: Check the page for posts, maybe we can reproduce the same request!

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but how would I do that?

Comment: First download: https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-br/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/ **|** open the Live Http Headers **|** unselect Capture **|** click clear **|** select capture **|** open the page **|** unselect capture **(**You can just try with capture on the hole time, just makes harder to find the request later**)** if you do this way the first request will be the one you are looking for.

Comment: I got it thanks, In a second when it updates and realizes you have enough reputation to chat ill start one if thats okay
?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30569/discussion-between-peter-and-gorfi)

Answer (score 1):

Depending, of course, on the camera model you have, you must use a complex URL to get directly to the image.
I have FOSCAM compatible cameras, where the full URL looks something like

```
http:_//_username:password@ip address/snapshot.cgi
```

This gets me directly to the image, no splash screens or anything.
Whats your camera make and model?

Comment: By the way, you don't need to call Client.Dispose(). The GarbageCollection does that for you.

Comment: Thank you the url for my camera is similar its a sanyo vcc-4600 and the url is `http://username:password@ip address/liveimg.cgi` but even when you go to the url for the first time it brings you to the language page. I believe it is saving a cookie with the language after the first selection. I found the cookie in my browser. Any way to take advantage of this?

Comment: Thanks for the up-vote!
You'd have to find a way to store that cookie and/or send a mock cookie upon your first request. But that is beyond the WebClient capabilities, I believe. Maybe with the GetWebResponse-method, I'm not sure.